# Backbone Click Anchor Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I am starting a Web Application from scratch and I am using Backbone. So to start I was trying to have my whole app associated with a View, binding some anchors ( with internal links ) to a click event which gets the href and navigate to that, like this:

```
var App = new ( Backbone.View.extend( {
...
events : {
    'click a[data-internal]' : function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        Backbone.history.navigate( event.target.pathname, { trigger : true } );
    }
},
start : function() {        
    Backbone.history.start( { pushState : true } );              
}

}))({ el : document.body });

$( function() { App.start(); });
```

Then i have the following html:

```
<li>
    <a href="/messages" data-internal="true"><img src="assets/img/mail.png" alt="Mensagens" title="Mensagens"></a>
</li>
```

My problem is, when the event is fired the event.target is always associated to the img child and not to the anchor. It doesnt seem to be something about bubbling. I have already tryed to use e.stopPropagation(). With no inner img it works well.

I don't understand why this happens. Can someone explain it to me?

Thanks a lot ;)

EDIT:
I solved the problem using event.currentTarget as ho.s suggested.

Comment: I cannot really explain why this happens, BUT if you log your "event" `console.log(event)` you will see that the anchor is the `currentTarget` and the image is (no surprise we already know :-)) the `target` element. so you can adress the anchor by using `event.currentTarget`

Comment: Thaks! I didn't know that existed a target and currentTarget. Know i understand the problem.

Comment: @ho.s: The difference between [`target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) and [`currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) is due to event bubbling: you're clicking on the `<img>` but the event bubbles up to the `<a>` before anyone cares about it. `currentTarget` is usually what you want in a Backbone app as `this` tends to be a view.